# Run gradle build(test) in subprojects in a custom task

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How to run task build or test some subprojects in custom task in build.gradle.kts?
For example, I have submodules: firstA, secondA, thirdA. I want to run build in custom task for only firstA and thirdA.

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "myProject"
include(
  "modules:firstA",
  "modules:secondA",
  "modules:thirdA"
)
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, are you talking about subprojects that have their own build files, or multiple testing sourcesets?

Comment: @Deadbeef, it is subprojects. I use multimodule project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register a gradle task in the root project, then iterate over the subprojects and filter them by their name, and then depending the task on the test tasks of the subprojects.

Example:

```kotlin
tasks.register("mytest") {
    dependsOn(subprojects.mapNotNull {
        when (it.name) {
            "firstA", "thirdA" -> it.tasks.findByName("test")
            else -> null
        }
    })
}
```